# Django - Retain Search Parameters between Server Round Trips

Tags: django, django-views

I have a list page with some filter, sort and search functionality (which basically creates a QuerySet in the view that then returns the adjusted (filtered, sorted, searched) data). On this list page, I also have a detail view that displays the object details.

This all works fine, but when I navigate to another detail object, the search, filter, sort parameters get reset to their default.

How can I retain the search parameters beyond a server round trip?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could store the GET parameters as session variables maybe?

To set:
`request.session['my_variable'] = request.GET.get('some_get_parameter')`

To get:
`my_variable_value = request.session.get('my_variable')`

Using `.get()` to retrieve parameters and session variables is a little more robust than just trying to access the dicts directly with `request.session['my_variable']` for example, as if `my_variable` is not in the session, you'll get a key error, but `get()` returns `None` if the variable is not found.